# What should be the ideal total dissolved solids level of drinking water?

Tags: water, water-filter-purifier

This is one of the most controversial and highly debated topics in India these days, especially since the popularity of reverse osmosis (RO)/UV filters started rising a few years ago. Even if you google for "ideal total dissolved solids (TDS) for drinking water", there isn't one agreed upon view it seems and the results are suggesting quite a variation in what should be the ideal TDS, which is a way of measuring water purity in terms of PPM (Particles Per Million).

This is especially an issue with RO filters as they purify waters to very low TDS levels in most cases. Incidentally, WHO's recommendation for safe TDS level (<=300 PPM) is much different than that of these water filter companies which is typically around 70-100 PPM!

The rational way of thinking is that lower is better and purer, isn't it? But the other camp insists that if water purity goes to absolutism levels (TDS<=20), the person won't get their quota of micro-nutrient minerals like Sodium, Magnesium, etc. But my question is, won't that person get those minerals through dietary sources like green leafy veggies, etc. anyway? Also, I've never heard yet (anecdotally) of anyone falling ill due to drinking low TDS water. However, "Is low TDS harmful" is apparently a trend online and you'll even find many high authority articles and even Youtube videos when you google this topic!

What research or official guidelines exist? Especially for someone who lives in bore-well water areas, should they use RO or not? My own experience here is that just using a normal candle filter with bore-well or salty water makes it hard to drink and it might even cause digestion problems. RO, on the other hand, makes the water sweet but is then subject to low-TDS as said above.

Comment: I think you need to reconsider your assumption that most people get adequate minerals and electrolytes from dietary sources like green leafy veggies. It might be true in India with its high preponderance of vegetarians, but I doubt it's true in most western countries. I've seen studies showing that 60% of Americans are deficient in magnesium, for example.

Comment: @CareyGregory That's true, that's why I worded it as a question, not a presumptious statement. It all depends on your health needs and there shouldn't be one constant rule in this regard.